# Multisort array of objects in a specific way

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

There is an array of objects

```
ar = [
    {name: 'a', count: 1},
    {name: 'c', count: 2},
    {name: 'f', count: 0},
    {name: 'e', count: 0},
    {name: 'b', count: 3},
    {name: 'a', count: 0},
];
```

I'm trying to sort it in such a way, that it is sorted by

1. count > 0
2. name alphabetically

so the resulting array would be

```
ar = [
    {name: 'a', count: 1},
    {name: 'b', count: 3},
    {name: 'c', count: 2},
    {name: 'a', count: 0},
    {name: 'e', count: 0},
    {name: 'f', count: 0},
];
```

I've tried several multisort approaches and the result is always close, but the part with 0 count is not sorted properly.

Comment: Please share your better try code.

Comment: A good and simple solution to overcome this by yourself would to to separate the objects into 2 groups `1. count > 0`, `2. the rest`, then sort each group by name, and join the 2 groups

Comment: @OmriAttiya i had the same idea but there is a solution in which you don't have to do this, check it below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subtract the boolean returned by `count > 0`. This will sort the items with `count > 0` with priority. If both items have the same priority, sort them based on the `name` property using [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

```js
const arr = [
  { name: 'a', count: 1 },
  { name: 'c', count: 2 },
  { name: 'f', count: 0 },
  { name: 'e', count: 0 },
  { name: 'b', count: 3 },
  { name: 'a', count: 0 },
];

arr.sort((a, b) => (b.count > 0) - (a.count > 0) || a.name.localeCompare(b.name))

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Why don't you use pretty straightforward way? I mean dividing an array into 2 arrays: one where all items have `count` > 0 and the second for the rest. Then sort both alphabetically. Then concat array back.

```js
    const ar = [
        {name: 'a', count: 1},
        {name: 'c', count: 2},
        {name: 'f', count: 0},
        {name: 'e', count: 0},
        {name: 'b', count: 3},
        {name: 'a', count: 0},
    ];
    
    const pCount = [];
    const nCount = [];
    ar.forEach((item) => {
        if (item.count > 0) {
            pCount.push(item);
        } else {
            nCount.push(item);
        }
    });
    
    pCount.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
    nCount.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
    
    const result = [...pCount, ...nCount]; // concat 
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: Splitting arrays and sorting each looks like an extra, this could probably be useful in different, more complex cases

Comment: @AlexandrF. Agree. I also agree that the accepted answer is better. But this one looks much more clean and understandable for beginners. And it also works. Thats why I didn't delete it ;)